# Convert decimal minutes to hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to convert a value for example 2.54 that comes in minutes to a format like hh:mm:ss.
the value could be also zero.

Comment: for example ? is the decimal number always represent minutes ?

Comment: With 2.54 I think you mean 2 minutes and 54 seconds .. right?

Comment: yes, the values comes always in decimal minutes

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @f DECIMAL(6,2) = 2.54

SELECT CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, 60 * ROUND(@f, 0, 1) + 100 * (@f % 1), 0) AS time(0));

@f=2.54    ->    00:02:54

@f=330.42  ->    05:30:42
```

How it works:

ROUND(@f, 0, 1) - minutes; take only the integer part, discarding everything after the decimal point

[MS Docs ROUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

100 * (@f % 1) - seconds; take the remainder of the integer division by 1

[MS Docs %(Modulus)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

`DATEADD(SECOND, X, 0)` equivalent to `DATEADD(SECOND, X, '1900-01-01 00:00:00')`

[MS Docs DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

CAST(X to time(0)) - trim date from DATETIME

[MS Docs CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the solutions:

```
select
2.54 as NumericTime
,floor(2.54) as Minutes
,(2.54-floor(2.54))*100 as Seconds
,cast('00:'+cast(floor(2.54) as varchar)+':'
 +cast((2.54-floor(2.54))*100 /* or 60 if this is common format */ as varchar) as time) as FullTime
```

But I really don't like all this additional CASTs. Maybe someone can provide better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
DECLARE @f DECIMAL = 2.54;

SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(MINUTE, 60*@f, 0));
```

Gives result as

```
02:32:00
```

Comment: Unfortunately it shows results: 12:57:36, 12:57:35, 18:43:12. My DB Collation is Cyrillic_General_CI_AS.

Comment: @AlexPeshik, that's correct. I interpreted it wrong. OP means 2.54 in minutes.

Comment: Updated part with SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(MINUTE, 60*@f, 0)); shows result '03:00:00' on my server...

Comment: @AlexPeshik, not sure, I tried in SQLFiddle. BTW, I just ran your answered query; is that the outcome OP looking for? Also, other than casting many time, your solution looks good to me, provided that's what OP wants.

Comment: I don't know what means .54: minutes/seconds and 100/60-rank format. I believe my server shows '03:00:00' because of collation...

Comment: @AlexPeshik, Yes, question lacks clarification. I will keep my answer for now; once OP clarifies that my answer is outbound then will remove it.

Comment: does is works for you guys? the value comes always in decimals and represent minutes that has to be converted to hh:mm:ss

Comment: @rgx71, have you checked Alex Peshik answer? That looks fine to me.

Comment: I replaced 2.54 by 330.42 and is not working, gives me an error and is not showing the hours

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, what do you think? not very elegant but it's work.

```
DECLARE @number DECIMAL(12,4) = 2.54
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN @number >= 60 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), FLOOR(FLOOR(@number) / 60)) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (FLOOR(@number) % 60)) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FLOOR((@number-floor(@number)) * 60))
       ELSE '00:' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), FLOOR(@number)) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), FLOOR((@number - floor(@number)) * 60))
       END
```

Comment: Sorry..didn't see Rahul's post..blame lack of sleep

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Convert(time(0),CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(MINUTE, 60*@f, 0)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Time DECIMAL(4,2) = 3.07
SELECT CAST(floor(@Time) AS VARCHAR) + ':' 
       + REPLACE(REPLICATE('0',5 - LEN(CAST(@Time%1*100 AS VARCHAR))) 
       + CAST(@Time%1*100 AS VARCHAR),'.',':');
```

This will also handle the corner cases where the Time is 2.05 sec, 4.09 sec etc.